# WPF Canvas Overlay - ToolTIp/ Data Trigger issues

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

i'm having issues with hide/showing 2 elements.  By default the Canvas is visible, based on a state, a data trigger will hide the Canvas (Opacity 0%) and show a button/image (Opacity 100%).

The button has a tooltip/cursor, it is overlayed ontop of the canvas. When shown tooltip/cursor stops working. When it is not overlayed anywhere on the canvas, the attributes work.

I think the canvas, is taking precedence even though it is hidden/disabled/opacity=0%.

Is there anything i can do in the data trigger to retain the button tooltip?

Answer (score 0):

Set the `Canvas.IsHitTestVisible="false"` in addition to the opacity = 0%. You can find more information about hit testing [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752097%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hiding the canvas by setting it's opacity to 0, simply set the Visibility property of the Canvas to Collapsed.